# Do you need an email address per Twitter account?

Tags: twitter, account-management

I have a Twitter account for myself, associated with my primary, personal website. However, I run a few other sites as well, not really related to my own, and wonder about having Twitter accounts to correspond to those sites.

Does each Twitter account have to be registered with a separate email address, or can the same email address be used to register multiple Twitter accounts?

I'm not doing this for spamming or anything like, but simply to add a communication channel for these other sites. In the end, I'm the one that will be using these accounts.

Comment: Have you tried registering with the same email adress?

Comment: @GoodEnough Just tried it, got "Email has already been taken." back.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like you said in the comment, you apparently can't have the same email address for many accounts. However, if you have a Gmail address, you could use a very neat Gmail feature.

Just add `+something` to your Gmail address, like so

```
example+website1@gmail.com
```

and use this address to register in Twitter. All mail will automatically be in your `example@gmail.com` inbox.

Comment: That's a neat trick! Was able to register the new account I wanted using a modified email address. This might get a proper email address in the future, but I could change the email address on the Twitter account. This technique will do for now.

Comment: The `+something` is not really a Gmail-specific thing (see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Address_tags)), but +1 nonetheless.

Comment: @jonik but gmail is the only one advertising it. I've just tried it on my work and my school address, and none of them worked. So GO GMAIL! :)